# Chat room for gathering close/reopen votes for questions?

Tags: support, chat

I have seen mentions in various places on Stack Overflow of a chat room that exists so that users can post links to questions to try and gather close or reopen votes for that question.

I found a question today I think deserves reopening, and so I went in search of this chat room. I'm not sure what it's called, though, and a search for the common terms you might expect in the name yielded no results.

Can someone point me in the direction of this chat room please?

Comment: It seems that it's [currently frozen](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus), whoops.

Comment: @TimStone Oh dear!  How do we unfreeze it?

Comment: Ah, thanks to Random for unfreezing it!  Tim if you'll post the link as an answer I'd be glad to accept :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The room you're probably looking for is [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131713/popular-demand)'s [Posse Comitatus](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus), which you might have had some trouble finding because it had been frozen due to inactivity.

It seems that it's been unfrozen [by the power of <s>Greyskull</s> random](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1016989#1016989), so you should be able to both find and post in that room now.

Comment: I usually just go to the Tavern xP

Comment: Time to remove/update?